# PHP POST request not working when http:// in variable

Tags: php, forms, post

I have this really wierd question.

When I submit my form, if one of the variables is, say http://www.youtube.com, the page gives a `NO DATA RECEIVED` error and fails.

Not sure if it is a server setting, or something I can fix in the PHP script.

The post processing script is very simple for testing:

```
<?php
foreach($_POST as $a=>$b) echo "{$a}={$b}<br />";
?>
```

This is fine on some servers, not on others, which makes me think it's a server setting.

Any insight will be gratefully received

Comment: What php version do you have ?

Comment: can you post your form

Comment: Ask your hosting provider. They most like have mod_security or suhosin.

Comment: It could also be your browser. Chrome is known to have a "NO DATA RECEIVED" problem with certain lines of PHP code

Comment: Do you have the suhosin patch installed?

Comment: Instead of that ugly `foreach`, just use `echo '<pre>' . print_r($_POST, true) . '</pre>';`.

Comment: Hey folks, thanks for all the great answers. The problem was mod_security as you suspected. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things to check for in `php.ini`:

- `post_max_size` # should be different from 0
- `variables_order` # should be = "EGPCS"
- `max_input_vars` # should be higher than the number of variables you pass

Things to check for in the HTML form:

- the fields and submit button are inside the form
- the form has `method="POST"`
- if the form has files, check the enctype, it should be `multipart/form-data`, if not it should be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
- Look for `<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="..." />` - is it big enough ?

If all are fine, check if [mod_security](http://www.howtoforge.com/apache_mod_security) is enabled, and also check .htaccess for things like `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST`, and the rule after it.

Check if your browser sends the data. In Chrome network tab I see something like this:

[image]

---

You can also try the following:

```
var_dump(get_defined_vars());
```

or

```
$vars = get_defined_vars();
foreach ($vars as $var) {
     echo "<br><b>{$var}</b>";
     var_dump($$var);
}
```

and check the list of declared variables.

**PS:**

I presumed that you use Apache, since you **didn't include this info**. Also, try a different browser, and see if it changes anything.

**PS2:**
I like to check config settings in the command line with:

```
~$ php -i | grep -i variables_order
variables_order => GPCS => GPCS
```